# GTA 5 Rank 10 and I still cannot unlock crew Spray?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am currently Rank 10 in GTA 5 and I still cannot unlock crew sprays. Is it an in-game bug, or should I do something specific?

Answer (score 7):

If you are referring to the crew paint job color for cars, you need to be level 20.

From [IGN's Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Crews) on Crews:

> - Level 20 - Able to set crew emblem decal, and color on cars

I believe that this is your **Crew level**, and **not your character level**.

Comment: Just to add a little more information to the post: You can check your active crew level by navigating to the Rockstar Socialclub website, click on your active crew and when you're on the crew's page select 'GTA Online'.